# Spark YARN client on Windows 7 issue

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to execute

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client
```

on windows 7 client machine for CDH 5.4.5. cluster.
I downloaded spark 1.5. assembly from spark.apache.org. 
Then downloaded yarn-config from cloudera manager running on cluster, and wrote its path to env variable YARN_CONF on client.

Yarn application worked correctly, but client gets the exception

```
15/10/16 10:54:59 WARN net.ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py 10.20.52.104
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py" (in directory "C:\workspace\development\"): CreateProcess error=2, ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.runResolveCommand(ScriptBasedMapping.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.resolve(ScriptBasedMapping.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.resolve(CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.coreResolve(RackResolver.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.resolve(RackResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler.getRackForHost(YarnScheduler.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$1.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$1.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:262)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint.makeOffers(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$processMessage(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply$mcV$sp(AkkaR
pcEnv.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$akka$AkkaRpcEnv$$safelyCall(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:126)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1.aroundReceive(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:93)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, ═х єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ Їрщы
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 38 more
```

Then I modified client configuration of yarn site.xml param "net.topology.script.file.name" to correct path and now client get the exception

```
15/10/16 10:48:57 WARN net.ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running C:\packages\hadoop-client\yarn-conf\topology.py 10.20.52.105
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\packages\hadoop-client\yarn-conf\topology.py" (in directory "C:\workspace\development\"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 эх  ты хЄё  яЁшыюцхэшхь Win32
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.runResolveCommand(ScriptBasedMapping.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.resolve(ScriptBasedMapping.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.resolve(CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.coreResolve(RackResolver.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.resolve(RackResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler.getRackForHost(YarnScheduler.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSetManager$$addPendingTask$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSetManager$$addPendingTask$1.apply(TaskSetManager.scala:192)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSetManager$$addPendingTask(TaskSetManager.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSetManager.scala:161)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
```

As I understood, spark can't invoke topology.py script correctly using python.exe on windows, but how to fix it?

Comment: Just an opinion, almost every single developer on [apache-spark] is using some form of Unix and usually popular linux distros like Ubuntu, RHEL. Your odds of finding help will exponentially increase if you jump in to the Linux wagon.

Comment: Hi mehmet, that is true. It is more or less of scientific interest for me to get Spark on Yarn running on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a comment "net.topology.script.file.name" yarn param in site.xml.

Comment: For use spark you must download from cloudera manager client configuration files to client node. http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cm_mc_client_config.html      Comment specified param in yarn site.xml configuration with "<!-- -->"

Comment: I'm not using Cloudera.

Comment: Nevertheless, as I saw, specified issue does not affect spark application execution result.

Comment: Once again I do not understand what you are saying. I don't even get a result since my spark jobs are not even submitted due to the issue described above.

Comment: You want to submit spark app at windows machine not in cluster, do you? For that aim you've downloaded spark distributive (the same version as the cluster ??) and tried to execute 'spark-submit' on your windows, right? Spark won't start without knowlege about cluster topology and some hadoop binaries (winutils.exe). You must get hadoop binary distributive for windows the same version your cluster is, download yarn configuration files (for cloudera from Cloudera Manager). Finally, set environment variables 'HADOOP_HOME' and 'YARN_CONF_DIR'. Aaaaaaaand... edit the yarn site.xml described above.

Comment: Commenting the script will compromise the [rack-awareness feature of Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/RackAwareness.html). There needs to be a better solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as above on HortonWorks HDP2.4 when trying to access it with an iPython notebook with Spark. I solved it with the proposal from @mikhail-kramer above.

On the Windows client, I had to comment out the value of the net.topology.script.name variable in file core-site.xml that I had downloaded using Ambari. The commented out value now looks like this:

```
<property>
  <name>net.topology.script.file.name</name>
  <value><!--/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py--></value>
</property>
```

I hope that this may help the next person who has the same problem in the future.